# Photoshop: Where are the "Pressure for Opacity" and "Pressure for Size" in the custom shortcuts feature?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts, wacom

I am setting up Photoshop commands/tools/functions on a Wacom and would really like to have the "Pressure for Opacity" and "Pressure for Size" options as shortcuts—which would be very useful. There isn't a keyboard shortcut assigned to either of them by default and I tried searching in the custom shortcuts feature and looking it up online, but haven't found anything.

Where are "Pressure for Opacity" and "Pressure for Size" in the custom keyboard shortcuts feature in Photoshop?

You can check out the pictures below, to better get what I am referring to.

Regards.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Good news: Adobe has recently added both of these in the custom keyboard shortcuts function, in the 2015.5 release, all the way at the bottom of the 'Tools' list.

Wohooo!

[image: https://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-8858495-975777/tog.png]

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, Adobe doesn't support those buttons and even the Actions function don't record them. However i had a similar problem once and with [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) software i could do right about everything in Photoshop, but not only.
By using this software you can record a mouseclick at a given position - so, create a macro that snaps your cursor to that location and clicks it, then return.

Comment: To Mac users, I found  [Keyboard Maestro](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153930/autohotkey-equivalent-for-os-x), which can do macros with image recognition (probably cursor location as well, but don't know for sure).

Comment: I'm on a (photography) school iMac, so I don't know if I am going to be able to mess around with the account authorizations and such, so I am still actively looking for other solutions.

Comment: With pleasure @samseva

Comment: I've also found [Auto Mouse Click](http://www.murgaa.com/mac-auto-mouse-click/), which having tried the demo seems it might work.